# How to get back the old behavior of grouped summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in 6 domains, with between 2 and 6 measures per domain, or 25 measures in all. There is one set of measures inside domains for 42 networks. I want to `summarize` the measures within each domain within each network. I use `group_by(network, domain)` and expect to get out 6 cases in each network. However, now the results I get have the same structure as the original data -- 25 cases per network. Here's the code:

```
testing <- all.meas.qs.2 %>%
   group_by(network_id, domain) %>%
    reframe(emerging.pct=sum(emerging)/construct.num,
            achieving.pct=sum(achieving)/construct.num)
```

I have to use `reframe()` instead of `summarize()` because it yelled at me for producing less than or greater than 1 output line per group. I believe my code in the original behavior of `summarize()` would only return 1 line of output per group (6 lines per network) and would not yell at me.

```
Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
i Please use `reframe()` instead.
```

To get around this problem I regrouped the output data frame and kept 1 line per group with `slice(1)` I don't know if what I did is OK.
Things apparently changed with version 1.1.0 of dplyr. How do I get back the old behavior?

Comment: Notice that you are dividing by a vector, meaning you will have n values per group. You are `mutat(e)`ing rather than `summariz(e)`ing

Comment: I agree with @onyambu.  Also, I suspect the warning message you quote points to a potential error in your original code (running without error does not mean it produces correct results), but without a *minimal reproducible example*, I cannot be sure.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a MRE.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting. Thank you, @onyambu and @Limey. I think I see the problem. I summarize to get the sum of the `emerging` variables (which are coded {0, 1}), which produces an atomic vector, and then divide by the length > 1 vector `construct.num`, producing a vector length > 1. Now it makes sense. So, maybe I should divide each `emerging` by the `construct.num` with `mutate()` and then `summarize` to get the percentage? I'll try it.